# Creating a cURL like request in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, curl

I got a request working perfectly when I created a request in cURL but I needed to make it c# code so I can add it to our system. This is the cURL request that I am trying to make a similar request in c# but had no luck on creating a correct one:

```
curl "https://someurl.com" -X PUT -d "@somefile.json" -H "Authorization: XXXXXX"
```

This is the current code that I have:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(path + "somefile.json", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
putClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "XXXXXX");
var response = await putClient.PutAsync(SOME_URL, httpContent);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with C# code?

Comment: I'm getting INVALID_DATA from the server where I am calling the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it and is very easy. I modified this code:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(jsonstring, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

It turns out that I don't really need to send a json file, sending a json string will be fine.